# Картинка по ширине

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Здравствуйте, как сделать следующие:
Есть код

```
<div class="container">
<div class="item"><img src="/img/01.jpg"></div>
<div class="item"><img src="/img/02.jpg"></div>
<div class="item"><img src="/img/03.jpg"></div>
<div class="item"><img src="/img/04.jpg"></div>
<div class="item"><img src="/img/05.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Ширина класса container ровна 100%, ширина класса item ровна 20%, то есть на каждую строку рассчитано по 5 картинок, каждая картинка должна принимать размер родителя, я не могу обозначить ширину картинки в пикселях, так как ширина монитора у всех разная, как быть?

Comment: `float:left`

Comment: =) это понятно, а шарину как правильно задать? представим монитор у юзера 1000px, задал я ширину картинки 200px, все ровно круто, заходит юзер с монитором 1400пх, у него уже картинок в строке не 5 а 7, а нужно что бы было всегда 5. И так же картинки должны полностью помещаться в ширину, то есть свободных мест быть не должно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Стили**

```
.container, .item { display: inline-block; }

.container { width: 100%; }

.item { width: 20%; }

.item img { width: 100%; }
```

Только не забудь убрать все пробелы между картинками

**2) Таблицами**

```
.container { display: table; }

.container { width: 100%; }

.item { display: table-cell; }

.item img { width: 100%; }
```

Пробелы между картинками не важны

**3) Как подсказали уже - через float**

```
.container { width: 100%; }

.item {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}

.item img { width: 100%; }
```

Пробелы между картинками не важны

Answer (score 0):

С чего друг картинка должна растягиваться по ширине родителя??
ну если конечно ты и управляешь еще и картинкой, то...

Пример:

```
<div id="bg">
    <img src="images/bg.jpg" alt="">
</div>

#bg {
    position:fixed; 
    top:-50%; 
    left:-50%; 
    width:200%; 
    height:200%;
}
#bg img {
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    right:0; 
    bottom:0; 
    margin:auto; 
    min-width:50%;
    min-height:50%;
}
```

правда не будет работать в опере и в ie < 8

Остальные примеры тут: [link text](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)