# Как реализовать вывод фото на странице по размеру

Tags: php, css

Здравствуйте. Разрабатываю страничку для мобильных устройств. 
В .css файле установил максимальную и минимальную ширину страницы:

> max-width: 640px;
>   min-width: 400px;

Максимальная ширина у меня равна экрану в 4 дюйма.

На странице мне нужно вывести 2 фотографии.

Каким образом рассчитывать размер этих фото, для того чтобы они стояли рядом, без переноса на следующую строку(т.е. не так чтоб второе фото находилось под первым), учитывая разрешение экрана пользователя?

Буду благодарен за любую полезную информацию.

Comment: width:49% не вариант ?  height не указывать

Comment: @LenovoID Это как-то очень просто. Возможно у этого решения есть какие-то недостатки?

Comment: [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/154293/5079) похожий вопрос, можете адаптировать один из примеров к вашему случаю

Comment: а вы хотите сложное решение ? чем проще тем лучше